# what is the part number of genuine full retail non-OEM non-MSDN non-Academic non-Upgrade Windows 7 Pro w/ 32-bit and 64-bit DVDS?

Tags: windows-7, licensing

what is the part # of genuine full retail non-OEM non-MSDN non-Academic non-Upgrade Windows 7 Pro w/ 32-bit and 64-bit DVDs?

(So I know what I'm installing...)

Comment: I didn't even know they had part numbers. . .

Comment: I believe you have the CDs/DVDs or can download them but not sure what they are. if so, google the part# and it should give you some results.

Comment: Thanks, but what is "google"?

Comment: The part number(s) change, pretty often.